# Spin Tool starting rotation not 0 degrees

Tags: modeling

[image]I'm trying to use the spin tool but it always starts off its axis at 
(.847, -.466, .255). I want to start it off at (0,0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just click one of the blue Plus signs.
And then change the *Angle* back to 0.

Yeah, it could behave a bit better :).

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. It works now.

Comment: Happy to help, learned something new myself :).